# wso2 3.2 how to browse H2 DB console

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2 3.2. I just wanted to browse the local H2 DB.
Can anyone know the full steps?

I am did some changes in deployment.toml file as below & restarted the server, but the
console is not opening.

```
[database.local]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:C:/Tools/wso2am- 
3.2.0/repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
enable_h2_console = "true"
port = "1010"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"


[database.apim_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:C:/Tools/wso2am- 
3.2.0/repository/database/WSO2AM_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"
enable_h2_console = "true"
port = "1010"



[database.shared_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:C:/Tools/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/
database/WSO2SHARED_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" 
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"
enable_h2_console = "true"
port = "1010"
```

Comment: Can anyone please suggest ?

Comment: Is there anything else that I need to do ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following configuration to the `deployment.toml`.

```
[database_configuration]
enable_h2_console = true
```

Reference: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/reference/config-catalog/#enabling-the-h2-database-console

Once the H2 console is loaded, enter the JDBC URL, Username and Password to Connect to the database.

According to your configuration, enter the following values to connect to the `apim_db` database.

```
JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:C:/Tools/wso2am- 
3.2.0/repository/database/WSO2AM_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
User Name: wso2carbon
Password: wso2carbon
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Download a DB Client like [Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) and then create a new H2 Database connection pointing to the DB location in the file system, in your case, `C:/Tools/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/database/WSO2AM_DB` then add the credentials and connect.